# Poker etymological dictionary

Tags: poker-history

Is there a Poker etymological dictionary out there that explains the origin/history of the poker terms? There are many terms in Poker with meanings that are not immediately obvious and it'd be nice to find out their origins, for example terms such as *cow*, *broadway*, *cooler*, *coffee housing*, *come bet/betting on the come*, etc...

Comment: I don't think there will be a dictionary explaining the etymology of poker slang as some of it is quite obscure. For example I have no idea why broadway is called broadway, I mean it makes sense you could say something like- "there's nothing better than broadway" (comparing it to theatre) but I don't actually know where it comes from. There are some cases where you might be able to find out though, for example  the term "three bet" doesn't really make much sense in NLH but that is because it has its origins in PLH

Answer (score 1):

Some of the terms are defined here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_poker_terms.

Some etymology here: http://www.flopturnriver.com/top-10-poker-lingo.php

Comment: Oh yes, but they only define it they don't give their etymology. For example, why does broadway called broadway, or why does cooler called cooler?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like this site: http://pokerterms.com/

It does answer your cow question (and many others): http://pokerterms.com/cow.html

This is good too: http://www.poker1.com/archives/2344/wiesenberg-official-dictionary-of-poker-mcu-intro but has a drawback: When you search you have to search the whole site, not only the dictionary